# Different Tap Recognizer for Subviews

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I am using a `UIView` as a container to hold a `UILabel` and an `UIImageView`.

I want both the `UILabel` and `UIImageView` to have a `UITapRecognizer` **BUT:** The Different functions.

```
    let gesture3 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self,
    action: #selector(chatViewController.clickOnGroupImage(_:)))
    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture3)

    let gesture2 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self,
    action: #selector(chatViewController.clickOnButton(_:)))
    labelView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture2)
```

Now after putting both as subviews to my container, I am not able to click them (It worked fine, when I tested both methods just on a single Container).

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the `userInteractionEnabled` is `true` for the views which you are applying gestures (`imageView`, `labelView` in your case), also enable user interaction for container.